# The happiness of migration

Tags: esp32

For many days I've been trying to make a raycasting engine for Arduino in which 3 steps are essential
-**making a 3d environment (done)**
-**making the player move (pending)**
-**hand the player a assault rifle (pending)**
So,here I have problem with the movement of player which I have no I idea with ,I have tried dozens of ways to make the player move but it just glued to one place.If anyone can help then it will be just amazing.I have made this project on wokwi btw.If anyone knows about wokwi then you can also help me there  https://wokwi.com/projects/392425187841246209. **AND** This is gonna run on a esp32 ,display the game in tft display and inputs by 5 push buttons ......Here's the code

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_ILI9341.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define TFT_CS     15
#define TFT_RST    -1
#define TFT_DC     33

#define BUTTON_UP    4
#define BUTTON_DOWN  36
#define BUTTON_LEFT  34
#define BUTTON_RIGHT 35

#define TFT_WIDTH   320
#define TFT_HEIGHT  240
#define MAP_WIDTH   15
#define MAP_HEIGHT  15

Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

int worldMap[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT] = {
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};

double posX = 13.0, posY = 7.0, posZ = 0;
double dirX = -1.0, dirY = 0.0, planeX = 0.0, planeY = 0.66;
double speedVar = 0.50, rotSpeedVar = 0.1;

void setup() {
  tft.begin();
  tft.setRotation(1);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(BUTTON_UP, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(BUTTON_DOWN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(BUTTON_LEFT, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(BUTTON_RIGHT, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  handleInput();
  movePlayer(1); 
  renderWalls();


}
// Button states
bool upPressed = false, downPressed = false, leftPressed = false, rightPressed = false;

void handleInput() {
  // Read button states
  upPressed = !digitalRead(BUTTON_UP);
  downPressed = !digitalRead(BUTTON_DOWN);
  leftPressed = !digitalRead(BUTTON_LEFT);
  rightPressed = !digitalRead(BUTTON_RIGHT);

  // Update player position based on button presses
  if (upPressed) {
    posY -= speedVar;
    dirY = cos(rotSpeedVar) * dirY - sin(rotSpeedVar) * dirX;
    dirX = sin(rotSpeedVar) * dirY + cos(rotSpeedVar) * dirX;
  }
  if (downPressed) {
    posY += speedVar;
    dirY = cos(-rotSpeedVar) * dirY - sin(-rotSpeedVar) * dirX;
    dirX = sin(-rotSpeedVar) * dirY + cos(-rotSpeedVar) * dirX;
  }
  if (leftPressed) {
    posX -= speedVar;
    dirX = cos(rotSpeedVar) * dirX - sin(rotSpeedVar) * dirY;
    dirY = sin(rotSpeedVar) * dirX + cos(rotSpeedVar) * dirY;
  }
  if (rightPressed) {
    posX += speedVar;
    dirX = cos(-rotSpeedVar) * dirX - sin(-rotSpeedVar) * dirY;
    dirY = sin(-rotSpeedVar) * dirX + cos(-rotSpeedVar) * dirY;
  }
}

  


   void movePlayer(double deltaTime) {
   //Ensure the player stays within the map boundaries
    posX = constrain(posX, 0.0, double(MAP_WIDTH - 1));
    posY = constrain(posY, 0.0, double(MAP_HEIGHT - 1));
    }

void renderWalls() {
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);

  for (int x = 0; x < TFT_WIDTH; ++x) {
    double cameraX = 2 * x / double(TFT_WIDTH) - 1;
    double rayDirX = dirX + planeX * cameraX;
    double rayDirY = dirY + planeY * cameraX;

    int mapX = int(posX);
    int mapY = int(posY);

    double deltaDistX = abs(1 / rayDirX);
    double deltaDistY = abs(1 / rayDirY);

    int stepX, stepY;
    double sideDistX, sideDistY;

    if (rayDirX < 0) {
      stepX = -1;
      sideDistX = (posX - mapX) * deltaDistX;
    } else {
      stepX = 1;
      sideDistX = (mapX + 1.0 - posX) * deltaDistX;
    }

    if (rayDirY < 0) {
      stepY = -1;
      sideDistY = (posY - mapY) * deltaDistY;
    } else {
      stepY = 1;
      sideDistY = (mapY + 1.0 - posY) * deltaDistY;
    }

    bool hit = false;
    int side;
    while (!hit) {
      if (sideDistX < sideDistY) {
        sideDistX += deltaDistX;
        mapX += stepX;
        side = 0;
      } else {
        sideDistY += deltaDistY;
        mapY += stepY;
        side = 1;
      }
      if (worldMap[mapX][mapY] > 0) hit = true;
    }

    // Calculate perpendicular distance to wall
    double perpWallDist;
    if (side == 0) {
      perpWallDist = fabs((mapX - posX + (1 - stepX) / 2) / rayDirX);
    } else {
      perpWallDist = fabs((mapY - posY + (1 - stepY) / 2) / rayDirY);
    }

    // Calculate wall height
    int lineHeight = int(TFT_HEIGHT / perpWallDist);

    // Calculate draw start and draw end
    int drawStart = max(0, -lineHeight / 2 + TFT_HEIGHT / 2);
    int drawEnd = min(TFT_HEIGHT - 1, lineHeight / 2 + TFT_HEIGHT / 2);

    // Draw the wall slice
    int color = (worldMap[mapX][mapY] == 1) ? ILI9341_RED : ILI9341_WHITE;
    tft.drawFastVLine(x, drawStart, drawEnd - drawStart + 1, color);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any answer will be grately appreciated

Comment: You seem to confuse a few things here, therefore first a few questions: Do you want the buttons to move the character in first-person manner or in a global context (should "up" mean "move forward" or "move to the north")? What's the meaning of the dirX and dirY variables? You want to change position, not direction, I suppose?

Comment: Your button actions look confusing, as if they each do both translation and rotation. Also, it looks like you only wired the UP button. For some reason, Wokwi reads the other three buttons as LOW (pressed).

Comment: add debug code to your program

Comment: the wokwi code works ... the player moves backward

Comment: And I don't want that I want it so that the player will only move when a push button is pressed

Comment: Arduino SE is a Q&A site. you seek project guidance. for that forum.arduino.cc is better